# Does AngularJS fit into the (3)-tier architecture?

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns

This is rather an academical question but maybe someone can give me a hint here. What kind of architecture is AngularJS? First I thought about a 3-tier archtiecture:

Presentation-Layer: HTML5 / CSS
Application Layer: AngularJS
DataLayer: AngularJS (??)

...but thinking a while longer basically does this fit in a multi-tier architectural design pattern at all?

Because Angular has a two-way binding whereas changes within the view affect the model (data-layer) without going through an application layer here. Furthermore Angular directly touches the DOM. So I ended up with:

Presentation-Layer: AngularJS (manipulating DOM)
Application-Layer: AngularJS
Data-Layer: AngularJS

So how can AngularJS be described the in terms of design patterns?

Comment: Interesting question but pretty much opinion based.AngularJS has nothing to do with a 3-tier architecture that describes application servers,not presentation frameworks.

Angular is a presentation framework that implements the Model View Presenter pattern.and forces dependency injection.

3-tier architectures are end to end application architectures and wider systems.They dont describe javascript DOM frameworks.There is no database server in angularjs,nor business object server.

Comment: I disagree on your point that a 3-tier architecture is only intended for application servers and wide systems. The 3-tier architecture also exists within software where certain modules handle a certain aspect. MVC (however this is interpreted) is a representation of this: Model (Data-Layer), View (Presentation-Layer), Controller (Business Logic).

Comment: Except MVC is not a 3-tier architecture.A 3-tier architecture has a specific meaning. MVC at best,is a vague design pattern.A MVC webframework backend by a database is not even a 3-tier architecture.If the 3 components of a 3-tier architecture are not in different (physical) servers,it is not a 3-tier architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AngularJS has an MVW structure model-view-"whatever works for you" [link](https://plus.google.com/+AngularJS/posts/aZNVhj355G2)

So, you decide what you need it to be.